# Iterating Through a Single Vector and Deleting Elements that Are Subsets of Other Elements?

Tags: c++, string, vector, iterator

I am trying to iterate through a single vector (using two iterators) to delete elements that are subsets or copies of other elements (the vectors are ). What I have below compiles but the program execution stops early (not all subsets or copies are deleted). I have read in strings from a file and placed them in vectors: sequence_1 and sequence_2 . Any help would be very much appreciated.

```
int c,j; string first_sequence, second_sequence;
vector<string>::iterator ivector1; vector<string>::iterator ivector2;
vector<string>::iterator ishort;

 // all relevant headers to the material are included in original code
//comparison of vector elements

size_t location,x,y,k,s;

k = sequence_1.size();
s = sequence_2.size();

for(ivector1 = sequence_1.begin(); ivector1< sequence_1.end(); ++ivector1){

    for(ivector2= sequence_1.begin()+1;ivector2<sequence_1.end(); ++ivector2){
        first_sequence = *ivector1; second_sequence = *ivector2;

        if(*ivector1 == *ivector2){
           cout << "Deleting the sequence with id: <" << endl << *ivector2 << endl;                                                         
        sequence_1.erase(remove(ivector2,sequence_1.end(),*ivector2),sequence_1.end());

        } else if(*ivector1 != *ivector2){
                    x = first_sequence.size();
                    y = second_sequence.size();

                    if(x > y){
                        location = first_sequence.find(second_sequence);
                        if (location != -1){
                             cout << "Deleting the sequence with id: <"<< endl << *ivector2 << endl;
                                                sequence_1.erase(remove(ivector2,sequence_1.end(),*ivector2),sequence_1.end()); 
                    }

                    } else if (y > x) {
                            location = second_sequence.find(first_sequence);
                                    if (location != -1){
                                            cout << "Deleting the sequence with id: <"<< *ivector1 << endl;
                                            sequence_1.erase(remove(sequence_1.begin(),ivector1+1,*ivector1),sequence_1.end());

                                    }

                    }
          }
    }
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

When you erase from a `vector` all iterators pointing to the deleted item or beyond it are invalidated.

Your first `erase` call looks like it will invalidate `ivector2` which means the rest of that loop will be unreliable, and your second `erase` call looks like it can potentially invalidate both your iterators.